# Restrict ajax throbber to specific form id

Tags: 7, ajax

Can we restrict below code to specific form ,currently its working on all form wherever ajax is calling.

I am using ajax throbber module in drupal 7.

```
<?php
/**
* @file
* Drupal module file ajax_throbber
*/

/**
* Implements hook_page_alter().
*
* @param $variables
*/

     function ajax_throbber_page_alter(&$variables) {

    {
  // Preferred color to css.
    $throbber_selection = 
    variable_get('ajax_throbber_selection',
    'circle');
  // 0, 174, 239, .8
  // 0,255,0, .8
    $bg_color = variable_get('ajax_throbber_bg_color', '255,255,255, .8');
  $item_color = variable_get('ajax_throbber_item_color', '0, 174, 239, .8');

  drupal_add_js(array(
    'ajaxThrobber' => array(
      'bg_color' => $bg_color,
      'item_color' => $item_color,
      'type' => $throbber_selection,
    )
  ), 'setting');

  // Add correct css file and return correct html.
  $html = _ajax_throbber_add_correct_throbber($throbber_selection);

  // Add the HTML.
  $variables['content']['system_main']['ajax_throbber'] = array(
    '#weight' => -10,
    '#markup' => $html,
  );
//}
}

/**
 * Add correct css file.
 */
function _ajax_throbber_add_correct_throbber($throbber_selection) {
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_throbber');
  $module_css_path = $module_path . '/css/stylesheets/ajax_throbber_';

  // Default HTML.
  $html = <<<HTMLTHROBBER
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="bounce1"></div>
    <div class="bounce2"></div>
    <div class="bounce3"></div>
  </div>
HTMLTHROBBER;

  switch ($throbber_selection) {
    case 'circle':
      // Last example.
      drupal_add_css($module_css_path . 'circle.css');
      $html = <<<LOADINGCIRCLEHTML
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="spinner-container container1">
      <div class="circle1"></div>
      <div class="circle2"></div>
      <div class="circle3"></div>
      <div class="circle4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="spinner-container container2">
      <div class="circle1"></div>
      <div class="circle2"></div>
      <div class="circle3"></div>
      <div class="circle4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="spinner-container container3">
      <div class="circle1"></div>
      <div class="circle2"></div>
      <div class="circle3"></div>
      <div class="circle4"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
LOADINGCIRCLEHTML;

      break;

    case 'fading_circle':
      drupal_add_css($module_css_path . 'fading_circle.css');

      break;

    case 'square':
      drupal_add_css($module_css_path . 'square.css');

      break;

    default:
      drupal_add_css($module_css_path . 'three_dots.css');
  }

  return '<div class="overlay-spinner">' . $html . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I had written about this in the past, but the best way to do custom progress indicators is to extend the core Drupal function that defines progress types, and add your own. Then, in forms, specify that custom type when defining ajax on form elements.

Comment: i am new to drupal can you share me the link